# How do I enable users to have a browse button (by clicking on the image icon)so that they can upload a picture.

Tags: wysiwyg

I added a user to my website and I gave him the permission to use blocks.
I activated wysiwyg and TinyMCE so that he can add also images.

But he has a problem, when he clicks on the icon to add an image then it opens a window where u can add the image url, image description,... but there is no browse button so that u can upload a picture.

thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to thank evryone that tried helping me!

I found an answer on my question

go to confrigation>IMCE>[profile] and under Directories use php: return 'users/'.$user->name; It will create user folders in Sites>default>files>users

And then the user gets a browse button to upload pictures.

Answer (score 1):

You need a  combination of the [imce module](https://drupal.org/project/imce) and [imce bridge module](https://drupal.org/project/imce_wysiwyg) to do this

**IMCE**

> IMCE is an image/file uploader and browser that supports personal
>   directories and quota.

**IMCE BRIDGE**

> Allows to use IMCE module with Wysiwyg module.

Comment: I see now that IMCE Wysiwyg API bridge is enabled, is it the same as IMCE BRIDGE?

Comment: yes it is the same

Answer (score 0):

[One Click Upload](https://drupal.org/project/ocupload) Module could also do this for you

Comment: I installed it, do you know maybe what I have to do by the configuration?

Comment: @user20263 Pls. read the instructions it's there : 

`Install One Click Upload
Extract module archive in sites/all/modules
Enable module One Click Upload
Download SWFUpload v2.2.0.1 Core, extract archive in sites/all/libraries and rename dir SWFUpload v2.2.0.1 Core to swfupload. 
After this file swfupload.js must be available on path sites/all/libraries/swfupload/swfupload.js.
Drush users can use the command drush ocupload-dl-library`

Comment: thank you very much! I did everything, but now when I go to buttons and plugins to enable one click upload its not there,  maybe because I use wysiwyg with TinyMCE and not with ckeditor?

Comment: Read the instructions and compatibility information in detail.

Comment: I red the istructions and installed everything corectly, afterwards I saw this: Integrate to Wysiwyg+CKEditor. So my question to you was if there is a solution what to do if I use TinyMCE